# How to find the terminal name associated with a process reliably in C?

Tags: c, terminal, posix

See the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("ttyname(0): %s\n", ttyname(0));
    printf("ttyname(1): %s\n", ttyname(1));
    printf("ttyname(2): %s\n", ttyname(2));
    printf("ctermid(NULL): %s\n", ctermid(NULL));

    /* Sleep for sometime so that we can manually run the ps command to
     * see the terminal associated with the process. */
    sleep(10);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile and run this as follows.

```
$ gcc foo.c
$ ./a.out 
ttyname(0): /dev/pts/3
ttyname(1): /dev/pts/3
ttyname(2): /dev/pts/3
ctermid(NULL): /dev/tty
```

In another terminal, I run the `ps` command to confirm the terminal name.

```
$ ps -ef | grep a.out | grep -v grep
coder     1498  1473  0 19:19 pts/3    00:00:00 ./a.out
```

Everything is good so far. My program prints the terminal correctly.

However, my program fails to output the terminal information when stdin, stdout as well as stderr are redirected as follows.

```
$ ./a.out < /dev/null > foo.txt 2> /dev/null
```

In another terminal, I run `ps` and I can see that indeed `/dev/pts/3` is associated witht he process.

```
$ ps -ef | grep a.out | grep -v grep
coder     1536  1473  0 19:22 pts/3    00:00:00 ./a.out
```

But after `./a.out` exits and I check its output in `foo.txt`, I don't see this information captured.

```
$  cat foo.txt 
ttyname(0): (null)
ttyname(1): (null)
ttyname(2): (null)
ctermid(NULL): /dev/tty
```

Since `ttyname()` fails to provide any meaningful information when stdin, stdout and stderr are redirected and since [`ctermid()` always returns `/dev/tty`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/sysdeps/posix/ctermid.c), what can I do to reliably determine the terminal associated with a process? I am ideally looking for a solution that works on any standard Unix or Linux system, but if that is not possible, then Linux specific solutions are also okay.

Comment: Why, after you redirect stdin/out/err to /dev/null, would you think it's still attached to a terminal?

Comment: @KevinDTimm I don't think it is still attached to the terminal. That's not my question. I am completely aware that stdin, stdout and stderr are not attached to the terminal when I redirect them. But the process is still associated with the terminal (as you can see from the `ps` output). If the process is still associated with the terminal, how can I get that terminal name from within the process using C code? This is what my question is.

Comment: Gotcha - checking

Comment: It may not be possible to reliably get the information you seek.  Why do you want it?  There may be an alternative that will serve your purposes.

Comment: See also related question [How to get the real name of the controlling terminal?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187319/74865) over on Unix & Linux SE.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - thanks John, that's what I was looking for - how `ps` finds this information

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> my program fails to output the terminal information when stdin, stdout as well as stderr are redirected

Well yes, `ttyname()` returns the (a) name of the terminal device that is open on the specified file descriptor.  When a file descriptor does not refer to a terminal, there is no such device.  `ttyname()` is documented to return `NULL` in this case, and any other in which the specified file descriptor is not associated with a terminal.

> what can I do to reliably determine the terminal associated with a process?

You first have to determine for yourself what "the" terminal associated with the process means.  In principle, file descriptors 0, 1, and 2, and maybe even more might all be connected to different terminal devices.  It might be that *none* of them are the process's *controlling* terminal, which I think is probably what you are actually looking for.

If a process wants to *access* its controlling terminal (supposing it has one), independent of redirection of its standard streams, then it ought to open the device named by the string returned by `ctermid()`, if any.  That glibc `ctermid()` always returns `"/dev/tty"` is irrelevant -- as devices are conventionally named, that serves as a synonym for the accessing process's controlling terminal.

As far as I can determine, however, there is no portable, reliable way to determine a process-independent name for *any* device, including a controlling terminal.  The kernel does not inherently work in terms of device names -- those live in the file system and are provided as a convenience for userspace processes.  Furthermore, any given device can, in principle, have multiple file names referring to it.

On Linux, however, you can get *the major and minor device numbers* of a process's controlling terminal from [`/proc/self/stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).  In principle, you can unpack these numbers and either

- convert them to the corresponding conventional file name, presumably with help from `/proc/devices`, or
- scan the `/dev` file system to find a matching device file, and report its name.

The former is less expensive, but somewhat speculative; the latter, if it succeeds, will return the name of a device file that exists and definitely refers to the desired device.

You could also check out the recommendations here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151812/get-device-node-by-major-minor-numbers-pair, but I find that at least some of them do not work on my system.

Comment: It is worth noting that "*the terminal associated with the process*" is a verbatim quote from the [ps(1) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ps). There, it refers to the controlling terminal, as reported by `/proc/*/stat`.